# How to make dynamic web page using ng-route in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

i've made web page. But when i try to click on some book my routes dont change, its always the same, on webpage there are always all of book instead of scoped one. I've tried almost everything and i still do not see what might be a problem. I'm sure in that i'm missing something but i dont see that.

```
        <div class="middle">
           <div class="book" ng-repeat="book in books | filter:searchBox">
                <img ng-src="{{book.pic}}" class="book-pic">
                <h1 class="book-title"><a href={{"#book/"+book.id}}>{{book.title}}</a></h1>
                <p class="author">{{book.author}}</p>
                <p class="description">{{book.description}}</p>
                <div class="price">
                    <p class="price-desc">{{book.price | currency  : "€"}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Js code:

```html
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

 myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider

         .when('book/:id', {
             templateUrl: 'book.html',
             controller: 'bookController'
         });
     myApp.controller('bookController', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

         $http.get("http://localhost/biblioteka/public/index/" + $routeParams.id)
             .then(function (response) {
                 $scope.book = response.data;
             });
     });

 });
 myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {


     // aside categories 

     $http.get("http://localhost/biblioteka/public/index")
         .then(function (response) {
             $scope.books = response.data;
         });

     $http.get("http://localhost/biblioteka/public/index/categories")
         .then(function (response) {
             $scope.categories = response.data;
         });
 });
```

Books have been converted to json file:

```html
$app->get('/index', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    // Sample log message
    $arr = [
        [  
            "id"=> 1,
            "pic"=> 'img/Nim-in-Action.jpg',
            "title"=> 'Nim in Action',
            "author"=> 'By: Dominik Picheta',
            "description"=> 'Nim is a multi-paradigm language that offers powerful customization options with the ability to compile to everything from C to JavaScript. In Nim in Action you’ll learn how Nim compares to other languages in style and performance, master its structure and syntax, and discover unique features.',
            "price"=> 35.59
            ],
        [
            "id"=> 2,
            "pic"=> 'img/31-Days-Before-Your-CCNA-Routing-Switching-Exam.jpg',
            "title"=> '31 Days Before Your CCNA Routing & Switching Exam',
            "author"=> 'By: Allan Johnson',
            "description"=> '31 Days Before Your CCNA Routing & Switching Exam  offers a friendly, practical way to understand the CCNA Routing & Switching certification process, commit to taking the ICND1 (100-105) and ICND2 (200-105) exams or the CCNA (200-125) exam, and finish your preparation using a variety of Primary and…',
            "price"=> 20
            ],
        [
            "id"=> 3,
            "pic"=> 'img/The-Python-3-Standard-Library-by-Example.jpg',
            "title"=> 'The Python 3 Standard Library by Example',
            "author"=> 'By: Doug Hellmann',
            "description"=> 'Master the Powerful Python 3 Standard Library through Real Code Examples The Python 3 Standard Library contains hundreds of modules for interacting with the operating system, interpreter, and Internet–all extensively tested and ready to jump-start application development. Now, Python expert Doug Hellmann introduces every major area of the…',
            "price"=> 45.50
        ],
        [
            "id" => 4, 
            "pic"=>'img/Visual-Basic-2012-Programmers-Reference.jpg',
            "title"=> 'Visual Basic 2012 Programmer’s Reference',
            "author"=> 'By: Rod Stephens',
            "description"=> 'The comprehensive guide to Visual Basic 2012 Microsoft Visual Basic (VB) is the most popular programming language in the world, with millions of lines of code used in businesses and applications of all types and sizes. In this edition of the bestselling Wrox guide, Visual Basic expert Rod…',
            "price"=> 10.8
        
        ],
        [
            "id" => 5,
            "pic"=> 'img/Windows-10-For-Dummies-3rd-Edition.jpg',
            "title"=> 'Windows 10 For Dummies, 3rd Edition',
            "author"=>'By: Andy Rathbone',
            "description"=> 'The #1 source for Windows 10 help Millions of Windows users have turned to Windows For Dummies for quick, friendly, and easy-to-understand help with their computers. Windows 10 For Dummies, 3rd Edition continues this tradition as it helps you navigate the twists and turns of Windows. Start at the beginning to discover the…',
            "price"=> 20
       
        ],
        
    ];
    
    $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($arr,true));

    // Render index view
    return $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it the wrong way. The `app.config` part is only used to configure services etc and we only have providers available to at `config` phase. However you are registering controllers inside the `config` which messes up the flow. You should move the controller part from inside the `config` section to either the separate file or in the same file but not inside the `config`.

Move this code out of config :

myApp.controller('bookController', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

```
         $http.get("http://localhost/biblioteka/public/index/" + $routeParams.id)
             .then(function (response) {
                 $scope.book = response.data;
             });
     });
```

Comment: I changed that but still it shows me same, all books :(

Comment: Have you placed a nested view in your SPA ?

Comment: Can you please mark this as an answer so that others can benefit from it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take out your controller from config

```
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider

         .when('book/:id', {
             templateUrl: 'book.html',
             controller: 'bookController'
         });
}

myApp.controller('bookController', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
  $http.get("http://localhost/biblioteka/public/index/" + $routeParams.id)
             .then(function (response) {
                 $scope.book = response.data;
             })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move controller from config part of code.

Move this part of code out of config :

```
   myApp.controller('bookController', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

             $http.get("http://localhost/biblioteka/public/index/" + $routeParams.id)
                 .then(function (response) {
                     $scope.book = response.data;
                 });
         });
```